# DateTime formatter

Tags: java, datetime, formatter

I am developing an application and I am stuck in converting `string` like `01/01/2037 01:00:00 AM`

to `Date`

I used

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy hh.mm.ss.S aa")

Date d = dateFormat.parse(dateString);
```

but I get an error, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You should add a tag to specify the language. Is it Java? Plus, when you get an error, post the code that throws it as well as the actual error message.

Answer (score 1):

you are converting this `01/01/2037 01:00:00 AM`

therefore use 
`SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss aa")`
(more info in [documentation])[1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html)
then

`Date date = dateFormat.parse("01/01/2037 01:00:00 AM");`

keep in mind you have to wrap a try-catch around the `parse` method.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the format you declared is nothing like the String you are trying to parse:

- your String uses / to separate day, month, year while in your formatter you use -
- your string separates hours with a dot, while in the formatter you use  :
- you do not have milliseconds in your string while you declared them in the formatter.

The following code should work:

```
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy hh.mm.ss.S aa");
    try {
        Date date = dateFormat.parse("01-01-2037 01.00.00.000 AM");
        System.out.println(date);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```